# Python - Writing JSON data to file

Tags: python, json

I have a Python function that generates a JSON output. I am trying to see how could I write this to a file.

```
{'logs': ['3982f208'], 'events': [{'sequence_number': 06972977357, 'labels': [], 'timestamp': 1556539666498, 'message': 'abc [2015-12-19 12:07:38.966] INFO [b5e04d2f5948] [ProcessController] PRMS: {"MessageType"=>"TYPE1", "Content"=>{"Name"=>"name1", "Country"=>"europe", "ID"=>"345", "Key1"=>"634229"}}}
```

I tried the below:

```
def output():   <-- This function returns the above JSON data
    json_data()
```

I tried to write it but creating a new function as below:

```
def write():
    f = open('results.txt', 'a'). <<- Creates the text file
    f.write(json_data)
    f.close()
```

This only creates an empty file. Could anyone advice as to how could I write the JSON data to the file.

Comment: What is `json_data`? Have it raised any errors?

Comment: That is not JSON, you will have to use [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage).

Comment: that is invalid JSON

Comment: `output()` does not return anything

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I tried to write the output from the earlier function (`def output()`)to the  `def write` function

Comment: It should be `return json_data()` and `f.write(output())`

Comment: I am pretty sure your output function doesn't return anything. You can double check by checking what `f.write()` returns. It should return the amount of bytes written. My guess is that in your case it'll be 0

Comment: @ThomasBartelmess He's never calling the `output()` function.

Comment: @ThomasBartelmess I am successfully able to return back the JSON data using `output` func.I am now trying to have this written to a file

Answer (score 0):

The `output()` function isn't returning anything, it needs a `return` statement:

```
def output():
    return json_data():
```

The `write()` function needs to call the `output()` function.

```
def write():
    with open("results.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(output())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `json` package I think this works:

```
import json
json_src = """{'logs': ['3982f208'], 'events': [{'sequence_number': 06972977357, 'labels': [], 'timestamp': 1556539666498, 'message': 'abc [2015-12-19 12:07:38.966] INFO [b5e04d2f5948] [ProcessController] PRMS: {"MessageType"=>"TYPE1", "Content"=>{"Name"=>"name1", "Country"=>"europe", "ID"=>"345", "Key1"=>"634229"}}}"""

# Can be wrapped in your write() function if you so choose
with open("results.txt", "a") as file:
  json.dump(json_src, file)
```

Comment: could you please assist in figuring how could I store the JSON output to a variable in `def output ()`